# How to select records when table includes multiple rows for each record with multi-criteria

Tags: sql, join, subquery, one-to-many, criteriaquery

I have a Student table:

```
| **Student**   |                                    |
|-----------|------------------------------------|
| StudentID | StudentName                        |
| 1         | Alfreds Futterkiste                |
| 2         | Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados |
| 3         | Antonio Moreno Taquería            |
| 4         | Around the Horn                    |
| 5         | Berglunds snabbköp                 |
| 6         | Blauer See Delikatessen            |
| 7         | Blondel père et fils               |
| 8         | Bólido Comidas preparadas          |
| 9         | John                               |
```

I have a Student Profile table

```
| **StudentProfile** |                        |      |            |
|----------------|------------------------|------|------------|
| StudentID      | Profile_Category       | Flag |            |
| 1              | DOB                    | Y    | 11/19/2022 |
| 1              | DoNotContact           | Y    | 10/25/2022 |
| 3              | AddressOnFile          | Y    | 9/13/2022  |
| 4              | SubscriptionPlanHolder | Y    | 8/8/2022   |
| 5              | DOB                    | N    | 11/1/2022  |
| 5              | DoNotContact           | Y    | 10/2/2022  |
| 5              | SubscriptionPlanHolder | Y    | 5/1/2022   |
| 6              | DOB                    | Y    | 10/27/2021 |
| 6              | SubscriptionPlanHolder | Y    | 11/11/2022 |
| 6              | AddressOnFile          | N    | 10/1/2022  |
| 9              | DOB                    | Y    | 9/9/2022   |
| 9              | SubscriptionPlanHolder | N    | 8/19/2022  |
| 10             | DOB                    | Y    | 11/11/2022 |
| 10             | SubscriptionPlanHolder | Y    | 10/1/2022  |
| 10             | AddressOnFile          | Y    | 9/9/2022   |
| 10             | DoNotContact           | Y    | 8/19/2022  |
| 11             | DOB                    | Y    | 11/11/2022 |
| 11             | SubscriptionPlanHolder | Y    | 10/1/2022  |
| 11             | AddressOnFile          | Y    | 9/9/2022   |
| 11             | DoNotContact           | Y    | 8/19/2022  |
```

**Desired output items**

- Select all students who got following profile attributes
  (Profile_Category = DOB **and** Flag = 'Y') **AND** (Profile_Category = SubscriptionPlanHolder **and** Flag = 'Y')

**In this case I should get StudentID 6, 10, 11*

- Select all students who got following profile attributes
  (Profile_Category = DOB **and** Flag = 'Y') **AND** (Profile_Category = SubscriptionPlanHolder **and** Flag = 'Y') **AND** (Profile_Category = AddressOnFile **and** Flag = 'Y')

**In this case I should get StudentID 10, 11*

- Select all students who got following profile attributes
  (Profile_Category = DOB **and** Flag = 'Y') **AND** (Profile_Category = SubscriptionPlanHolder **and** Flag = 'Y') **AND** (Profile_Category = AddressOnFile **and** Flag = 'Y') **AND** (Profile_Category = DoNotContact **and** Flag = 'Y')

**In this case I should get StudentID 10, 11*

So far, I have tried this approach but NOT getting the desired output:

**For desired output #1**

```
Select c.StudentID
FROM Student c
INNER JOIN StudentProfile p
ON p.StudentID = c.StudentID
WHERE Profile_Category IN ('DOB','SubscriptionPlanHolder')
AND Flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY c.StudentID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

**Getting: 6**

**For desired output #2**

```
Select c.StudentID
FROM Student c
INNER JOIN StudentProfile p
ON p.StudentID = c.StudentID
WHERE Profile_Category IN ('DOB','SubscriptionPlanHolder','AddressOnFile')
AND Flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY c.StudentID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

**Getting: 0 results**

**For desired output #3**

```
Select c.StudentID
FROM Student c
INNER JOIN StudentProfile p
ON p.StudentID = c.StudentID
WHERE Profile_Category IN ('DOB','SubscriptionPlanHolder', 'DoNotContact', 'AddressOnFile')
AND Flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY c.StudentID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

**Getting: 0 results**

Where I am getting confused is, how to bundle the different Profile_Category together because I am NOT looking for any one Profile_Category **(not looking for OR)**, goal is to get students who for all the desired Profile_Category **(looking for AND)** and corresponding flag is Y

Comment: So where you said: `...but NOT getting the desired output` ... what output are you getting? ... only 1 row of each student, or something else?

Comment: Hi @PaulT.  I just updated my post and shared the output that I am getting. Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems that taking the `student` table out of the queries gives the expected results? ... is there any particular need to join student if only needing the `StudentID` reference?